# HTML dinâmico via BD é má prática no PHP?

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Eu estou criando uma plataforma onde tenho necessidade de alterar elementos do site por um painel de controle, e por exemplo, seria algo muito *bad way* inserir no BD e puxar via PHP?

Digamos que eu tenho um menu com as seguintes opções em meu *menu*:

> **1.** Artigos
>
> **2.** Matérias
>
> **3.** Parceiros
>
> **4.** Promoções
>
> **5.** Contato
>
> **6.** Envie seu Texto

Imaginem que no BD está assim:

```
Id  | titulo                                        | status
```

---

```
1   | <li><a href="#">Artigos</a></li>              | 1
2   | <li><a href="#">Matérias</a></li>             | 1
3   | <li><a href="#">Parceiros</a></li>            | 1
4   | <li><a href="#">Promoções</a></li>            | 1
5   | <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>              | 1
6   | <li><a href="#">Envie seu Texto</a></li>      | 1
```

Vamos dizer que:

```
status 0 = oculto
status 1 = ativo
```

Apenas para exemplificar, o código, por exemplo, seria algo como isso:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <?php
    include('includes/conn.php');

    $query      = 'SELECT titulo FROM '.$tabela.' WHERE status = 1';

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($titulo);

            while($stmt->fetch()){

    ?>

        <?php echo $titulo; ?>
        <!-- COMNENT :: SAÍDA --
        <li><a href="#">titulo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Artigos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Matérias</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Parceiros</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Promoções</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Envie seu Texto</a></li> <<< ESTE NÃO APARECE
        -->

    <?php
            }
            $stmt->close();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Bem, eu poderia simplesmente mudar isso no banco de dados e colocar, por exemplo, a **opção 6** com status de "*oculto*" (status=0) e esconder esta opção do menu quando necessário.

Basicamente, isto consiste em uma plataforma com elementos dinâmicos se usado amplamente no projeto ou é má prática?

Comment: Penso que a parte de boa prática, vai de pessoa para pessoa... eu pessoalmente faço como você e penso que imensos projectos estão programados desta forma. Que outra forma tinhas de concluir essa operação?

Comment: Obrigado pela opinião. A outra forma seria simplesmente deixar esses objetos de comodidade de lado no PHP e tentar alguma solução em javascrpit.

Comment: Se você precisar criar uma tela que gerencie as opções, irá obrigar seu usuário a escrever todo o código HTML da opção? Ao meu ver, faz muito mais sentido você apenas armazenar a informação no banco e construir o HTML apenas na hora de exibir.

Comment: Má pratica não é, o wordpress faz isso e é um dos frameworks mais usados hoje. De uma pesquisada como ele faz isso, como guarda no BD, vai te dar uma idéia da melhor forma de guardar esses dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não acho que Wordpress seja um Frameworks necessariamente (até dá pra categorizar como tal), mas também não acho que seja um bom exemplo de como se fazer as coisas, na verdade acho que ele é um exemplo de **como não fazer** (ao menos na maior parte dos aspectos dele).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe uma só maneira de desenvolver em PHP e temos sempre que avaliar o contexto para definir a melhor forma de codificação. Uma boa prática é utilizar um padrão de arquitetura de software que seja coerente com o que é necessário. Um exemplo de padrão é o Model-view-controller (MVC), usado por frameworks como Zend, CodeIgniter, CakePHP, etc.

Caso seja usado esse padrão a base de dados terá somente os dados e não códigos (ou notações, como é o caso).
A camada de apresentação (view) terá somente a parte visual e não a lógica para buscar na BD, tratar e apresentar. O controlador que fará esta parte.

Portanto, na base de dados os dados serão armazenados de forma simples (que poderiam ser utilizados em outras partes da aplicação e não só no menu):

```
Id  | titulo               | status      | link
1   | Artigos              | 1           | #
2   | Matérias             | 1           | #
3   | Parceiros            | 1           | #
4   | Promoções            | 1           | #
5   | Contato              | 0           | #
6   | Envie seu Texto      | 1           | #
```

(Foi incluída uma coluna com o link porque não faria sentido ter os itens de menu sem um link.)

O controlador busca dos dados da BD e cria um objeto ou array com os menus ATIVOS. De forma simples, poderia ser uma function que retornasse um array com os itens de menu.

Na view pegaria somente o array e faria um loop para criar os itens da lista como por exemplo:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . $value['link'] . '">' . $value['titulo'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: concordo com você

Comment: Obrigado, @Everson . Fiz a alteração para desenvolver... aqui na minha terra "codificar" remete a escrever código-fonte :)

Comment: @Fernando acho que na terra de todo mundo :)

Comment: @Fernando show, se você acha que da forma anterior estava correta poderia ter deixado. Eu posso estar errado, nem sempre estamos com a razão. Como coloquei "porém EU não acho", diz que pra MIM não estava correto, então nem sempre "na terra de todo mundo" pode-se ler da mesma forma. Mas obrigado ;)

Comment: @Everson mostre onde codificar é sinônimo de compilar

Comment: https://www.dicio.com.br/codificar/ - na parte de `Sinônimos de Codificar`, foi aqui que busquei a informação.

Comment: @Everson Contextos completamente diferentes do que usamos. É disto que estou falando nesta página toda, sem contexto não podemos aplicar a regra geral.

Comment: Boa solução, Fernando!

Answer (score 9):

Eu discordo um pouco da outra resposta :)

O ideal é fazer o que precisa para o contexto do projeto, seguir regras impostas por outras pessoas que não conhecem o contexto daquele projeto é uma má prática, ou seja, é uma má prática seguir boas práticas. É uma boa prática conhecer boas práticas, entender profundamente a motivação dela para aplicar quando for o caso. Muitos projetos de software são ruins justamente porque seguem boas práticas sem entender o que está fazendo. E a maioria faz sem entender, mesmo achando que entende.

Por isso não posso dizer que MVC é adequado. Na verdade PHP e MVC pra mim é um pouco estranho, principalmente na forma como é implementado. Separar responsabilidades é bom, mas é preciso critério, fazer porque haverá ganho claro sem aumentar significativamente a complexidade do código. E tem modelo que separa a responsabilidade sem ficar complicado.

Eu não posso dizer se o que está fazendo é adequado ou não porque não sei o seu caso. Olhando por cima parece que não deveria porque não tem propósito, não tem necessidade.

Qual a dificuldade de fazer:

```
<li><a href="#"><?php $titulo?></a></li>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Html.php).

e não ter o HTML dentro do banco de dados? Pra mim é até mais simples fazer assim. É mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Você pode compor como desejar.

Você poderia colocar no banco se realmente o HTML é um dado que varie em cada operação. Mesmo isto eu diria que não é o mais adequado, mas novamente, não posso afirmar sem conhecer o contexto.

Comment: +1 - Essa frase resume quase todos os problemas que eu vejo acontecendo com os códigos em PHP: "... é uma má prática seguir boas práticas, É uma boa prática conhecer boas práticas, entender profundamente a motivação dela para aplicar quando for o caso"

Comment: Posso até concordar em parte com o que disse mas dizer que "é uma má prática seguir boas práticas" é forçar MUITO a barra. Sem radicalismos, por favor... ;)

Comment: @Fernando não é radicalismo, é a pura verdade. Tanto que evangelistas das boas práticas nunca tem nada a apresentar de código real. São muito bons em teoria vazia, mas no mercado, e em especial em PHP, "não cola". Veja projetos como Moodle e Wordpress, por exemplo. Muito bons até uma certa épica como exemplos, mas é um pesadelo de manutenção. O cara tem que virar especialista só naquilo pra manter qualquer customização.

Comment: E antes que alguém distorça, não é uma crítica ao funcionamento das plataformas mencionadas. Meus cumprimentos a ambas, por toda a filosofia de compartilhar tempo de programação e doar à comunidade produtos BEM completos. O único ponto em questão aqui é a idéia dos "padrões de arquitetura" e das "boas práticas" não funcionarem em ambiente real como solução de problemas, pois nos dois casos mencionados, acabou gerando complexidades desnecessárias em nome de uma versatilidade duvidosa para os programadores que chegam depois.

Comment: Queria muito ver aplicações como Moodle e Wordpress feitos com código sem padrão nenhum... seria lindo! Como disse, concordo em parte porque realmente temos que levar em consideração todo o contexto (ambiente, maturidade, complexidade, etc) antes de definir qualquer arquitetura. Agora, dizer que os padrões são teorias vazias e que "evangelistas das boas práticas nunca tem nada a apresentar de código real"  é sim puro radicalismo. Temos que avaliar todas as opções e adaptar o melhor para nossa realidade e depois seguir com ela para não ter um lixo legado.

Comment: @Fernando quem falou em padrão nenhum? Uma coisa que eu costumo dizer é que boas práticas é um mecanismo inventado com boa intenção e é ótimo. O problema delas é que quase todo mundo as seguem cegamente. A maioria sequer consegue interpretar o texto contido nela e acham que é só fazer o que alguém disse e tudo fica lindo. O problema é a atitude das pessoas que radicalizam em seguir algo sem entender porque estão fazendo aquilo, sem saber se precisam daquilo. Sua resposta fez o oposto do que está dizendo agora, qual está errado?

Comment: @Maniero, a minha resposta foi para tentar ajudar alguém que perguntou na comunidade como fazer algo que para mim é muito simples e o que achei melhor foi ajudar a indicar um caminho com explicação e código de exemplo. A minha esperança é sempre ter visões diferentes que mostrem formas de implementar diferentes para quem faz as perguntas em busca de alguma "luz", é para isso que estamos aqui. O problema para mim é o uso das palavras que indicam que não se deve levar muito em conta os padrões a quem está perdido e buscando alguma direção e por isso citei as frases que não concordo.

Comment: O mesmo vale na direção oposta. Inclusive eu só respondi pelo uso das suas palavras.

Comment: Realmente, lendo novamente minha resposta pode parecer uma posição muito direcionada mesmo tendo dito que não existe uma maneira de codificar, vou editar a minha resposta para evitar polêmica... às vezes o que é escrito acaba por parecer algo diferente do que é e estamos aqui para ajudar as pessoas e crescer juntos em conhecimento.

Comment: @Everson me desculpe, mas acho que você não entendeu bem o que é MVC. E mesmo que isto fosse verdade, na prática isto ocorre em 0,0001% dos casos, ou seja, complicar algo para uma possibilidade ínfima de ser útil não é um bom motivo.

Comment: @Maniero eu quis dizer que MVC é adequado porque você tem um ganho nessa parte de front e backend. Mas não relacionado a pergunta que teoricamente é simples. E na questão da outra resposta eu concordei na parte `Não existe uma só maneira de desenvolver em PHP e temos sempre que avaliar o contexto para definir a melhor forma de codificação`. Posso não ter a *noção* que você deseja que eu tivesse, mas não quer dizer que eu não tenha o direito de dar minha opinião. Posso estar errado, mas errando que se aprende.

Comment: Ninguém disse que você não pode dar sua opinião, e eu não desejo que você tenha nada, estou apenas lhe falando que MVC não é o que você pensa que é, pelo menos nesse contexto.